# How do I load an image in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, texture-mapping

I'm trying to map a picture of the earth at  night to a sphere with three.js, but I can't get it working. Everytime I refresh the page the image hasn't mapped to the sphere and in the console I get error 404 (Not Found). I've tried a lot of different ways to reference my image, but none of them worked.

This is my javascript code:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight);
camera.position.z = 3;
scene.add(camera);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const nightMapEarth = textureLoader.load("assets/nightmapearth.jpg");

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.7);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: nightMapEarth,
});

const earth = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, material);
scene.add(earth);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.append(renderer.domElement);

function animate() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

Comment: Could you check the url in your 404 error? is it correct?
if so - does your webserver allow access to this url? what happens if you open it up manually?

Comment: I have tried a lot of different url's but none of them seem to work. Even if I right click on the image file and click on 'copy path' or 'copy relative path' I still get the same error. I don't know if my webserver allows access to the url, but I have gotten an error that says not allowed to load local resource. If I open up the file manually it works and I'm able to see the image.

Comment: So there you have your issue, the webserver does not allow access to the image.
which webserver are you running? what does your config look like?

Comment: I don't know which webserver I'm using to be honest. But I've never changed my webserver, so I think I'm just using the default webserver for Windows, if that even exists. I also don't really know what you mean with config. I haven't been programming for a long time, so I'm sorry I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Look it up. Your server might be misconfigured to not serve images or media files in a sepcific folder.